# How to display the console logo during recording of a gameplay

Tags: video-recording

I am using the [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) app for creating recordings.
During recording of a game play, there is a console logo which gets recorded, too, as well as notifications.

How to avoid that?

[image: Logo]

Comment: Android itself does not support "recording of gameplay" therefore you seem to use a special app to do so. Please edit your question and name this app including Google Play Store link. Anyway if you are talking about a "console logo" you should provide a sample image of a video that shows this logo.

Comment: @Robert Wrong. I use the native "Play Games" app.

Comment: If the Google apps are part of Android is arguable...

Comment: @Robert well at least they should be knowing how to do that?! Wonder how to make the logo invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console logo when using Google Play Games appears when you are only recording the screen and not yourself. You can't remove it. It's either the console logo or your face (unless you block the front camera, then it will be a black circle that will be shown on your videos).

Your alternative is to record games using the screen recorder that comes installed with your phone (check if yours has one) or download a screen recorder apps from  Play Store.